# How can i get middle values in particular column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, infinidb

How can i get middle values in particular column in SQL 5.6, MySQL Workbench ie :

`5014.**160201**.1200.1-2` here i need the value `**160201**`

Comment: What does "middle value" mean?  Do all values follow the same form:  A.B.C.D-E?

Comment: No, It is like A.B.C.####    # INDICATES any value like D-E or D.E or D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the *second* value, based on the period separator, using `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(col, '.', 2), '.', -1) as second_part
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, Can u explain to me how that work.

Comment: @Kishore . . . https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index.

Comment: thank you so much for your valuable reference @Gordon Linoff